# How to get the URL of a Chrome webapp which is shown as a desktop app?

Tags: google-chrome

I have a Chrome webapp that was created using the "Add to desktop" feature.

This creates a "desktop like" app, which is executed in a separate window - without the url bar.

While using this app, I'd like to extract the url of one of it's pages. BUT, the URL bar is not shown.

I tried ctrl+l and using the menus, but couldn't find a way.

**How can I extract the URL of the current page I'm in?**

Answer (score 2):

Only way I can think off the top of my head would be to view the page source.

[image]

```
href=ThenSitename/page
```

There may be a better way im going to play around with some things an update my answer but this seems to be the best way so far. Since there is no address bar.

**EDIT:**

First find the page you want to get the url for.

Next Right click or hit the Following Key sequence <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

[image]

**Next click Sources**

[image]

**Then Below will be the current Url of the page you are on.**

[image]

Comment: This works only if the page links to itself, right?

Comment: Yes you are right about that.  I'm still trying to play around with it I will report back if I find anything better.

Comment: Found a better way. Updating answer.